# What does this red line mean at the bottom of my screen?

Tags: rendering, timeline

In my timeline there is a red line and I don't know what it means, I am a beginner and am really confused. also as I'm rendering my animation its just a grey screen and renders in 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: can you add as screenshot?

Comment: yeh sure @Noidea

Comment: hi can I have your email instead please? @noidea

Comment: It is **very** foolish to give your email to the public by posting it on a site like this! We as users are to remain mostly unknown for our own protection. Never ask for someone's email.

Comment: Questions asked here must have an answer here. If you want to chat or mail, don't ask in BSE.

Comment: @ric04 please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more information about your scene, are you doing physics simulations, particles, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This red line is probably particle baking.
When you add a particle system, a transparent red line appears in the timeline. When the particle system is baked, it appears bright red.
[image: particle bake line]

Comment: thanks a lot but I want to know why this red line keeps repeating in sense whenever it finishes I have to keep rendering and so on and so on? @bithur

Comment: I still don't get it?!?

Comment: this is another question, i suggest you ask it clearly with screenshots and/or your blend file. I don't think they are related.